# xts.coercible error while apply.daily on xts

Tags: r, xts

I have an intraday series (in xts) that I would like to aggregate into daily frequency: `apply.daily(mean(asd))`. It gives me:

> Error in try.xts(x, error = "must be either xts-coercible or timeBased") : 
>     must be either xts-coercible or timeBased

Does anybody know where this error might come from?

```
> head(asd)
                    EUR.USD.Close
2015-01-02 01:00:00       1.20875
2015-01-02 01:01:00       1.20870
2015-01-02 01:02:00       1.20880
2015-01-02 01:03:00       1.20890
2015-01-02 01:04:00       1.20885
2015-01-02 01:05:00       1.20885

> str(asd)
An ‘xts’ object on 2015-01-02 01:00:00/2015-01-30 22:59:00 containing:
  Data: num [1:28140, 1] 1.21 1.21 1.21 1.21 1.21 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "EUR.USD.Close"
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
List of 4
 $ from   : chr "20150421  09:00:00"
 $ to     : chr "20150501  09:00:00"
 $ src    : chr "IB"
 $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2015-06-07 01:46:37"
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax would be

```
  apply.daily(asd, mean)
 #                   EUR.USD.Close
 #2015-01-02 01:05:00      1.208808
```

For more info, check the `?apply.daily` and the examples in that page.

I can reproduce the error with the wrong code syntax

```
 apply.daily(mean(asd))
 #Error in try.xts(x, error = "must be either xts-coercible or timeBased") : 
 # must be either xts-coercible or timeBased
```